# Android NDK superuser permissions

Tags: android-ndk

I have a C program which I can run my rooted Android phone. However, in order to work correctly, the program must be run as superuser.

I now wish to call a method from this program using the Android NDK interface. What must I do to have the native code run as superuser?

Comment: Looking at http://markmail.org/message/6nl6xzck3bcxe676#query:android%20permissions%20ndk+page:1+mid:wypyp3oyj2mtzc57+state:results, it appears that the native portion of the applications (ie the C) run with the same permissions as the rest of the application, (i.e. the Java part). The question is then how to specify that the application itself should be run with root permissions. Is it something in the Manifest file?

Answer (score 0):

You should run the `su` program, and then script it (by writing to its standard input) to run your program. On some rooted devices, this will "just work", and on others (most, really) it will spawn an activity from an app called SuperUser to ask the user if it should be allowed.